# Adding a STL viewer to Joomla

Tags: joomla, module, stl

I would like to be able to view STL files in my Joomla website. But it seems that there isn't any module like this in the Joomla extensions directory.

Do you know where i can find a module like that?

If not, is it possible to use this http://codecanyon.net/item/stl3d-viewer/3222913?s_rank=4 to create a new joomla module ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I first tried to use various modules already present : Pred3Dviewer, webrotate360 but they don't correspond to what I would like to do. I also tried to use X3DOM which worked quite well but the file format supported is only x3d and i would like to use STL.

Comment: I downloaded the stl 3d viewer on code canyon. There are html, css and js files. How can I integrate this in a joomla extension? The viewer works in my web browser when i click on the html link